# How to dynamically/constantly bind jQuery eventhandler on a selection of buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a way to bind an click-eventhandler with jQuery to a div-container.

While this div-container is rerendered every 10 sec, 
jQuery lose the binding to the div-container.

How to prevent this?

This is how my div-Container looks like:

```
<div id="container">    
<h:panelGroup id="panel" layout="block">
    <h:form id="form">                                              
            <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="call-button" rel="#overlay"></div>      
            </div>              
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Here some Javascript:

```
$('div.call-button[rel]').on('click').overlay({
                    //show overlay
                });
```

your help is appreciated

Comment: What is:`.overlay({})` ???

Comment: it is jQuery overlay from jQuery Tools [link](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html)

Comment: This plugin doesn't seem to implement any kind of delegation, you have to reinitializate overlay plugin once new elements are added, inside ajax success callback for example. Ideally, you wouldn't reinitialize it on already initialized overlay elements, you have to find how to determine that, e.g checking for a specific class or data or whatever

Comment: Hi Wolff, thanks for your help. It is running now: calling the overlay now on pageload and (like you suggested) after every rendering through `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event delegation:

```
$("div.wrap").on("click", "div.call-button[rel]", function() {
```

Comment: DELEGATION ... okay, fine it works. But how to trigger the overlay this way. It will not show up with `$('div.wrap').on('click', 'div.call-button[rel]', false).overlay(...)`

Answer (score 1):

use event delegation since you are dealing with dynamic element delegation

```
$('#container').on('click', '.call-button[rel]', function(){
    //click handler
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('body').on('click','div.call-button[rel]', function(){
    //click handler
})
```